# Get collection name with BSON ObjectID in MongoDB using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

Is that possible to get collection name from `ObjectID` using `mongoengine` and `python`?

Example:

```
 "_id" : ObjectID('567795973920ea49f7b274eb')  ==> Belongs to collection "jObs" from 'mydb'
```

Wanted to print as collection name: `jobs`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094775/get-mongodb-collection-by-objectid.

Comment: @sangeeth kumar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow/86979#86979

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#ObjectIDs-TheBSONObjectIdDatatype):

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

In other words, `ObjectId` does not contain information about collection and database the object is in, so what you want is not possible.

Comment: Absolutely. However, in the link posted as comment to the question, Ross suggests you can use custom _id that would include the collection name.